# Find pattern across two rows then measure time between MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Data Table 
id dessert    time   user
1  eclair     10:00  Jon
2  banana     10:00  Mark
3  eclair     10:00  Paul
4  chocolate  08:00  Paul
5  eclair     10:00  Paul
6  chocolate  17:00  Jon
7  banana     21:00  Jon
8  eclair     21:00  Jon
```

I am aiming to get the average time, per user that it takes from them having the dessert "chocolate" to the dessert "eclair". In the listed example, it would have taken Paul two hours, whilst Jon was taking four. The rows aren't necessarily next to each other.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this? You haven't asked a specific question about what part of solving this you don't understand.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Lurker. I don't really know how to approach it, aside from initially selecting for "chocolate" then maybe a subquery for "eclair" I'm not trying to be obtuse, I just don't really know where to even begin. I can work out the datetime addition/subtraction stuff on my own, but getting a query to find a value, then find a second value isn't something I know how to do in MySQL

Comment: I think you should consider a self join. My hunch is that the answer provided so far is more complex than needed. Here's a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5cff0d/10) that gets you part way there you can play with.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use conditional aggregation:

```
select user,
       min(case when dessert = 'chocolate' then time end) as chocolate_time,
       max(case when dessert = 'eclair' then time end) as eclair_time,
       timediff(min(case when dessert = 'chocolate' then time end) as chocolate_time,
                max(case when dessert = 'eclair' then time end) as eclair_time
               ) as diff
from t
group by user;
```

This is the time between the *first* appearance of chocolate and the *last* appearance of eclair.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that any given user has no more than one chocolate and one eclair:

```
SELECT
    Chocolate.[user] AS Dessert_User,
    CONCAT(DATEPART(HOUR,DATEDIFF(HH, Chocolate.[time], Eclair.[time])),
                        ':', DATEPART(MINUTE,DATEDIFF(HH, Chocolate.[time], Eclair.[time]))) AS Time_Taken
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        dessert,
        [time],
        [user]
    FROM    
        table 
    WHERE 
        dessert = 'chocolate'
    ) AS Chocolate
JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        dessert,
        [time],
        [user]
    FROM    
        table 
    WHERE 
        dessert = 'eclair'
    ) AS Eclair
ON
    Chocolate.[user] = Eclair.[user]
```

Edited because I realized that I used syntax from SQL Server that I don't think works in MySQL.